# How to exactly define 9patch stretch and content

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I am desperately trying to get grips of the android-studio 9patch designer tool.

I have an icon. Above the icon, I'd like to have some text, displaying what the icon is about.

As far as I understand, I'd need to define that area to be the content. I guess the same area should also be the stretchable patches, as I'd need to keep the icon in its size and ratio as-is?

Here a simple illustration:

[image]

The bright blue area should expand according to the text, the icon should remain as-is.

I've achieved only partial success. I can write to the icon and set the text, but the whole icon expands, distorting the image.

My latest attempt produces errors in android-studio:

> No marked region found around edge

The docs to the 9patch drawing tool are quite poor IMHO. It just says the bottom and left indicators are for the patches, the top and right ones for the content. But I haven't managed to complete this supposedly simple task, I've already spent over a day on this...

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to specify the stretch area to that icon it will always distort, If you want the icon to be stay as it is then you need to cut them separately(icon & textbox field) using any image editor and use a layout that align the both of them where the blue box is using `nine patch` where it will be streach and the icon is just a simple `imageview`

Comment: hmmm. I understand, thanks. Trouble is this icon needs to work with google maps as marker. I am having trouble using two different Views (̣an `ImageView` and a `TextView`) as you suggest....

Comment: @faboolous you can always put it on the snippet view